# Are there any in-game meeting places for players?

Tags: elite-dangerous

- Are there any well-established locations where players will meet up in the *E:D* galaxy?
- Are there player-based groups (like the [Fuel Rats](http://www.fuelrats.com), but more social) that regularly gather in-game? If so, where?

I listen to the very awesome [Radio Sidewinder](http://www.radiosidewinder.com) and they sometimes mention bars for pilots to visit and get some R&R, or markets that sell exotic goods (there are no locations other than stations in the game yet, so maybe the markets are real, but I'm pretty sure there's no bars yet). I assume these are fake commercials intended to give the station a more realistic feel, but it made me wonder, if I'm lonely and want some guaranteed humanoid interaction, where can I go?

I realise there are traffic hot spots, such as the Sol system, stations that sell discounted ships, expansion systems, etc. There are also areas where [players gather to race](http://www.reddit.com/r/EliteRacers), which I have no desire to try and I'm not sure how you could spectate really, but it's pretty cool.

I'm looking for a "player-designated" hot spot, if that makes more sense.

Comment: For the record I do not mean anything unsavory by "guaranteed humanoid interaction". Just looking to meet some CMDRs and swap space stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a great answer to a **related** question on SE, [How can I find other players in Elite: Dangerous?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/238083/108888) that includes *some* relevant details. That question focuses on finding players anywhere, in any number. While I've come across my fair share of wandering players and 2-3 man wings, I was looking more for *specific locations* that **groups of people** tend to congregate around *habitually*.

The best and most relevant tips from that answer are as follows:

- This [list of subreddits](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/wiki/subreddits) leads to pages for many E:D groups, which sometimes give you an idea of where they gather, what they do, who they are, etc.
- There is also a suggestion to visit the "Old Worlds" that are mentioned in the original Elite fiction and games:

> Go to the "Old Worlds" cluster (Leesti, Lave, Zaonce, etc). This is the area that people started the original 1984 game in. There's a number of rare commodities available in the area, and multiple active player groups active in the area.

Without turning this into a continually-evolving list question, I think this is the best advice on finding player congregations at specific locations. These links will most likely continue to be accurate for at least the near future, if not longer.